# Debug output full of CDPurgeableResultCache logs on iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift

Since I started working on my iOS app with iOS 16 SDK, the debugger output is full of logs similar to the following ones, which makes the debugger output unusable for its purpose - debugging. I am quite sure these logs were not present on iOS 15.

```
2022-10-06 13:03:50.720934+0200 MyApp[4929:360382] [client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /private/var/hardware, setting to zero
2022-10-06 13:03:50.980913+0200 MyApp[4929:360382] [client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /private/var/wireless/baseband_data, setting to zero
2022-10-06 13:03:50.986746+0200 MyApp[4929:360382] [client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /private/var/MobileSoftwareUpdate, setting to zero
2022-10-06 13:03:50.994679+0200 MyApp[4929:360382] [client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /private/var/hardware, setting to zero
2022-10-06 13:03:51.178849+0200 MyApp[4929:360382] [client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /private/var/wireless/baseband_data, setting to zero
2022-10-06 13:03:51.184815+0200 MyApp[4929:360382] [client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /private/var/MobileSoftwareUpdate, setting to zero
2022-10-06 13:03:51.191255+0200 MyApp[4929:360382] [client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /private/var/hardware, setting to zero
2022-10-06 13:03:51.345517+0200 MyApp[4929:360382] [client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /private/var/wireless/baseband_data, setting to zero
2022-10-06 13:03:51.351931+0200 MyApp[4929:360382] [client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /private/var/MobileSoftwareUpdate, setting to zero
2022-10-06 13:03:51.363368+0200 MyApp[4929:360382] [client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /private/var/hardware, setting to zero
```

Searching online it looks like something from the system, but it's not present in

Comment: Same here: Any news about it ?

Comment: It looks it is related to a call to `URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() as String).resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey]).volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage` made from an old version of https://github.com/WeTransfer/Diagnostics