# Xcode log show CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals since update to version 14.1

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, realm, xcode14

Since I update my Xcode to version 14.1 when I run my app Xcode console show multiple lines of warning/errors

```
[client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /private/var/MobileSoftwareUpdate, setting to zero

[client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /private/var/hardware, setting to zero

[client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /private/var/wireless/baseband_data, setting to zero

[client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /private/var/MobileSoftwareUpdate, setting to zero
```

It also freeze after some seconds only when it run though Xcode.
It actually happened only on my real device not in simulator. My iPhone has version 16.1.1

I thought it could be my realm class but could not find any info about it. I don't use cocoapods. All my dependency are managed by SPM.

**Update**

This log error was related to a third party library use to share reports: https://github.com/WeTransfer/Diagnostics

Comment: For us to help we need to understand the use case - posting error messages with undefined variables doesn't really give us any relevant information. We need to see the code that's generating those errors and what `MobileSoftwareUpdate` etc is as we will have no idea. Also, including the version of Realm, and if you have a podFile, including that and your cocoapods version as well. Please update the question. Also take a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, Are you using any third party libraries?

Comment: @jay thank you for your comment I finally find the problem. I will take note of your suggestion next time I have any other question.

Comment: Solution from https://stackoverflow.com/q/74053157/12901229